# how binding textcolor in GroupHeaderTemplate label xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

it's possible to binding TextColor property label in GroupHeaderTemplate?

this is my source code:

```
 <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell Height="25">
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="5" 
                         BackgroundColor="#0477B3">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Key, Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}" 
                               TextColor="#ffffff" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

br
Max

Answer (score 0):

The BindingContext for a group is the grouping itself. Without knowing more about your code here is an example of how to bind to the grouping object in the group header template:

```
<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
        IsGroupingEnabled="true" GroupDisplayBinding="{ Binding Name }"
        GroupShortNameBinding ="{ Binding ShortName }">
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Height="25">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="5" 
                     BackgroundColor="#0477B3">
                    <!-- Name refers to Group.Name, depeding on your data you can use the key of your grouping here -->
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{ Binding Title }" Detail="{ Binding Description }" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And the code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<Group> groupedItems = new ObservableCollection<Group>();
        Group group = new Group("First Group");
        groupedItems.Add(group);
        Item item = new Item("First Item", "First Item Description");
        group.Add(item);
        this.BindingContext = groupedItems;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public String Title { get; private set; }
    public String Description { get; private set; }

    public Item(String title, String description)
    {
        Title = title;
        Description = description;
    }
}
public class Group : ObservableCollection<Item>
{
    public String Name { get; private set; }

    public Group(String Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

Example taken and modified from [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17976/listview-grouping-example-please)

Comment: very nice.. tanks

Comment: @MassimoDeVitis don't forget to upvote and mark as ansererd if you found it useful